# PySpark error: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to calculate the similarity between all of the two possible pairs of words from a column in a Spark data frame. I have created a UDF as well as a data frame to test the function, which I have defined them as follow:

```
   #Similarity Function
def lcs_similarityy(vector):
  metric_lcs = MetricLCS()
  p = []
  for i in vector:
    for j in vector:
      p.append(1 - metric_lcs.distance(i, j))
  return  p
   
   #UDF
lcs_similarityyUDF = udf(lambda z: lcs_similarityy(z))

   #Spark Data Frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(["GERMAN", "GERMANIA", "GERMANY", "LENOVO"], "string").toDF("Name")
```

I am expecting a column of 16 rows since there are 16 possible posible pairs. However once I test the function

```
lcs_similarityUDF(df.select("Name"))
```

I am given the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[Name: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I´ve been trying to fix this problem through different approaches but I cant make it work and I know very little about Spark and what could it be the problem. I dont know if I´ve made a mistake in the UDF or definig the data frame some any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your UDF as follows

```py
df.select(
    lcs_similarityUDF(df.Name).alias("Name")
)
```